# create a dataframe with a column that has %

Tags: r

I would like to create a dataframe like these

| State | % religious |
| --- | --- |
| QLD | 20 |
| NSW | 12 |
| WA | 10 |
| TAS | 8 |
| SA | 11 |
| VIC | 15 |
| NT | 22 |
| ACT | 18 |

I gave that code

```
religious <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  State = c("QLD", "NSW","WA","TAS","SA","VIC","NT","ACT"),
  % religious  = c( 20,12,10,8,11,15,22,18)
)
```

But when i gave % religious it comes error message?

Comment: thanks i saw this, but didn't solve my problem

Comment: But I think something is wrong with my wifi connection, it was because of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to put the irregular name in quotes and then turn off the automatic code that translates column names to valid R variables.

```
religious <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  State = c("QLD", "NSW","WA","TAS","SA","VIC","NT","ACT"),
  "% religious"  = c( 20,12,10,8,11,15,22,18),
  check.names = FALSE
)
```